# How to create 'Alias' like DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have this problem. Such a structure is generated programmatically

```
<ul id="container1">
  <li>Click 1</li>
  <li>Click 2</li>
  <li>Click 3</li>
</ul>
```

And on generation time click event handlers are assigned to these '**li**' elements. Basically clicking on any '**li**' hides the other '**li**' elements and only the one which is clicked would be visible.
Now what I want to do is to have the same navigation cloned with all it's behaviour and I want to show it also on the other part of the page. It would look like this then

```
<ul id="container1">
  <li>Click 1</li>
  <li>Click 2</li>
  <li>Click 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="container2">
  <li>Click Cloned 1</li>
  <li>Click Cloned 2</li>
  <li>Click Cloned 3</li>
</ul>
```

The trick here is, when I click on any '**li**' element under '**container2**', the action will happen on '**container1**', lets say If I click on '**Click Cloned 1**' on '**container2**', '**Click 2**', '**Click 3**' will disappear on '**container1**'. I must code this on pure JS and no external libraries are allowed. I tried many things and nothing worked. Do you have any idea how can I make container2 working as an alias of container1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below may be what you want (when an element in #container2 is clicked, the other elements in #container1 will disappear):

```js
var alias = document.querySelector('#container2').childNodes;

Array.prototype.slice.call(alias)
  .forEach(function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
      var that = this;
      var targets = document.querySelector('#container1').childNodes;
      Array.prototype.slice.call(targets)
        .forEach(function(ta, i) {
          if (ta.nodeType === 1 && !that.parentNode.childNodes[i].isEqualNode(that)) {
            ta.style.display = 'none';
          }
        })
    };
  });
```

```html
<ul id="container1">
  <li>Click 1</li>
  <li>Click 2</li>
  <li>Click 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="container2">
  <li>Click Cloned 1</li>
  <li>Click Cloned 2</li>
  <li>Click Cloned 3</li>
</ul>
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tmr7jwu/)